# 10 colons in 3 sentences in the 1928 Episcopal Nicene Creed: Why? How to parse?

Tags: punctuation, colons

Below is the text from [The Book of Common Prayer (1928)](http://justus.anglican.org/resources/bcp/1928/HC.htm). I have long-wondered why it is written with this punctuation. Perhaps there is no definitive answer to that question. But surely you can parse this. I am at a loss. There are ten colons in two sentences! (Eight semi-colons. That's a lot, but one can never have too many semi-colons in a sentence. Just kidding.)

I am asking today because I found "Can I use two colons in a sentence?" here, and that triggered my curiosity about the punctuation in this version of the Nicene Creed.

> I BELIEVE in one God the Father Almighty, Maker of heaven and earth, And of all things visible and invisible:
> ¶
> And in one Lord Jesus Christ, the only-begotten Son of God; Begotten of his Father before all worlds, God of God, Light of Light, Very God of very God; Begotten, not made; Being of one substance with the Father; By whom all things were made: Who for us men and for our salvation came down from heaven, And was incarnate by the Holy Ghost of the Virgin Mary, And was made man: And was crucified also for us under Pontius Pilate; He suffered and was buried: And the third day he rose again according to the Scriptures: And ascended into heaven, And sitteth on the right hand of the Father: And he shall come again, with glory, to judge both the quick and the dead; Whose kingdom shall have no end.
> ¶
> And I believe in the Holy Ghost, The Lord, and Giver of Life, Who proceedeth from the Father and the Son; Who with the Father and the Son together is worshipped and glorified; Who spake by the Prophets: And I believe one Catholic and Apostolic Church: I acknowledge one Baptism for the remission of sins: And I look for the Resurrection of the dead: And the Life of the world to come. Amen.

Comment: None of that punctuation is standard. https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Nicene_Creed_(ECUSA_Book_of_Common_Prayer) The Nicene is typically typeset and punctuated as given in the wiki page.

Comment: The version you link to is the 1662 Book of Common Prayer, which has its own conventions for punctuation etc. and can't be judged by the standards of modern usage. (Well, OK, the 1928 version, but that appears to be barely changed.)

Comment: Here is another standard version: https://www.churchofengland.org/our-faith/what-we-believe/apostles-creed#na Agree with Kate. The Book of Common Prayer typesetting is way out of date.

Comment: Thank you, @KateBunting. I should have done that much research. So I guess when the editors of the 1928 BCP were making changes, they probably decided not to mess with the 1622 punctuation. Anglicans certainly do evolve slowly. (I can say that. I'm an Anglican.)

Comment: @Lambie, may I argue? That is not the same creed. The Episcopalians diluted the creed in 1979 when they rewrote it as "we," abandoning the first person. By publicly stating "we" believe, they make it possible to participate in Episcopal liturgy without actually believing the creed oneself. They made it seeker-friendly, giving it the power to shape the soul of the unbeliever. I disapprove because by being seeker-friendly it dilutes the power for all the believers who aren't declaring their personal faith in corporate worship on a weekly basis.

Comment: **No, the link I posted from the CoE has exactly the same text as what you posted**. Whatever happened in 1979 is not germane to your question about punctuation, which reflects the 1928 version of the Book of Common Prayer. [And Latin is completely irrelevant here too.]

Comment: **I apologize and retract my criticism. I didn't see the first person singular version below the "we" version. Thank you for pointing to the modern punctuation.**

Comment: Perhaps bullet points and sub-bullets are seen as off-register.  But no one can argue with using paragraphs rather than paragraph marks. // If a good translation into the English of 1611 is seen as authoritative, it becomes hypocritical to be prejudiced against a good modern version of the Bible or creeds, abandoning archaic usages.

Comment: Sorry, the pilcrow was merely my stylistic choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer can be interpreted out of the comments. Kudos Kate Bunting for pointing out that the punctuation "barely changed" from 1662. This punctuation may have made sense to readers in 1622, but there is no reason to accept it in modern usage. And honorable mention to Lambie for a link to [the Nicene Creed with modern punctuation](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Nicene_Creed_(ECUSA_Book_of_Common_Prayer)) (Wikisource rocks!) and to FumbleFingers for a thorough critique of the punctuation.

Why? Because its origin is the 1662 version. How to parse? It doesn't parse.